# increment and backtracking in prolog

Tags: prolog, increment, backtracking

My purpose is to count the number of nodes between two nodes in Prolog. For example, in this example there is one node (node2) between node1 and node3:

```
link(node1,node2).
link(node2,node3).
```

Because we can't change the state of a variable already instantiated in Prolog, my first intuition was to try something with recursion like this to count:

```
nb_nodes_netween(N1,N2,R) :-
    link(N1,N2).
nb_nodes_netween(N1,N2,R) :-
    link(N1,A),
    T is R+1,
    nb_nodes_netween(A,N2,T).
```

My problem concerns the counter..
Thank you

**EDIT**
New version with R variable as OUT value (the final Result) and T variable as IN value (a kind of accumulator).

R = R + 1 but I have no idea how to translate this in Prolog. Maybe can I store the nodes in a list and T is the length of the list.

```
nb_nodes_between(N1,N2,R) :-
    link(N1,N2).
nb_nodes_between(N1,N2,R) :-
    link(N1,A),
    R is T+1,% TODO 
    nb_nodes_netween(A,N2,R).
```

Comment: You need one 'in' value and one 'out' value.

Comment: I think that it should be **nb_nodes_netween(N1,N2,0):-
    link(N1,N2).**

Comment: Hm I don't realy understand why. I think my problem is more to translate this step : Result = Result +1

Comment: `R = R + 1` is never true when you want to insert a concrete atom for `R`, the same goes for `R is R + 1` (2 is never the same as 3 etc.). You need a fresh variable `S = R +1` and pass `S` around as an additional argument to your predicate.

Comment: A possible way to approach the situation is to enumerate all possible paths from A to B via `setof/3` and count the length of the result. This only works if the number of paths is finite, so you will need to deal with cycles in your graph. (And you need to describe a path between A and B first).

Comment: What is R in `S = R +1`? because I have a fresh variable, she is T in my first post.

Answer (score 1):

So, the solution is quite simple:

```
nb_nodes_between(N1,N2,R,R) :-
    link(N1,N2).
nb_nodes_between(N1,N2,T,O) :-
    link(N1,A),
    R is T+1,% TODO 
    nb_nodes_between(A,N2,R,O).

?- nb_nodes_between(node1,node3,0,O).
O = 1
false
```

I want to point out a thing: suppose you have this knowledge base to represent the graph:

```
link(node1,node2).
link(node2,node3).
link(node3,node4).
link(node4,node2).
```

Try the query:

```
?- b_nodes_between(node1,node2,0,O).
O = 0
O = 3
O = 6
O = 9
O = 12
O = 15
and so on...
```

Whit this solution, if there is a loop in the graph, the programm will loop as well. To avoid looping and get ONLY one path, you have to add a cut `!` in your code, like this:

```
nb_nodes_between(N1,N2,R,R) :-
    link(N1,N2),!. %<-- note the cut !

?- nb_nodes_between(node1,node2,0,O).
O = 0
```

Comment: Thanks but I need only 3 parameters max then I need to found a solution to init T.

Comment: Simply rename `nb_nodes_between/4` in `nb_nodes_between_aux/4` and then create a `nb_nodes_between/3` predicate wich does: `nb_nodes_between(N1,N2,T):- nb_nodes_between_aux(N1,N2,0,T).` Done

Comment: In fact my constraint is that I can only create this predicate `nb_nodes_between/3` then my approach is probably bad to solve this issue.